# Unsupported TargetFrameworkVersion 4.6.2 for Azure CloudService Role

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, .net-4.6.2

I am trying to include worker role project targeting .NET 4.6.2 in my CloudService project which is on Azure 2.8. Upon building the CloudService project, I get the below error :

Error       The role Role1 is using an unsupported TargetFrameworkVersion v4.6.2.   CloudService    CloudService\objd\amd64\ServiceDefinition.csdef 1
Error       The role Role2 is using an unsupported TargetFrameworkVersion v4.6.2.   CloudService    CloudService\objd\amd64\ServiceDefinition.csdef 1

I also tried installing Azure 2.9.6 but couldn't get rid of this error.

Any pointers on this would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are your Cloud Service worker role deploy on **Guest OS Family 5 series**?

Only OS Family 5 series able to support **.NET Framework 4.6.2**.

[Azure Guest OS releases and SDK compatibility matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix#family-5-releases)

Comment: This is a visual studio build error. I haven't attempted deploying this yet.

Comment: The cause should be the same. I get the same error while deploying. But we trying to upgrade to 4.6.2 -> 4.7.2 with osFamily=7 (which is supposed to have 4.8 installed). I dont know why it was working with 4.6.2, but it fails with 4.7.2 while deploying